# Why do we call this 'homogeneous oscillation'?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

For a pde, a solution of the form
$u(x,t)=u_{*}(kx-\omega t)$

are sometimes called wavetrains.

Here, $k$ is the wavenumber and $\omega$ is the frequency.

Let $k=0$, then, I've heard that we are talking about "homogeneous oscillation".

What does this mean? If $k=0$, we have
$$
u(x,t)=e^{i\omega t}.
$$
Why does this represent "homogeneous oscillation"?

Comment: My guess would be that it means "independent of $x$".

Comment: Are you sure it was called "homogeneous oscillation" rather than "homogeneous oscillation [b]equation[/b]"? The equation is homogeneous because it does not involve known functions of x and t rather than u and its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation could be that it solves the *homogeneous* ODE given by

$\dot{u}(t)-i\omega u(t) = 0$